# PyDev plugin for Eclipse

Tags: python, ide

I just installed the PyDev plugin for Eclipse. Everything seems to be configured properly but I do not see syntax highlighting. D you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Have you changed the workspace view to pydev?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No code completion and syntax highlighting in Pydev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491053/no-code-completion-and-syntax-highlighting-in-pydev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not opening the file with the PyDev editor.

Make sure that the file association in window > preferences > general > editors > file associations for .py files is correct (it should be marked to be opened by Python Editor as the default option).

If it still didn't open, you can try right-clicking the file and choosing 'Open With > Python Editor'

Also, I'd recommend you follow the [PyDev Getting Started Guide](http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html)